# How to iterate over array of objects using oboe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, highland.js, oboe.js

I have a json response in the form of:

```
[{
  "id": 425055,
  "title": "Foo"
}, {
  "id": 425038,
  "title": "Bar"
}, {
  "id": 425015,
  "title": "Narf"
}]
```

I use oboe.js to create a highland stream:

```
const cruiseNidStream = _((push, next) => {
    oboe({
        url: 'http://fake.com/bar/overview,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-AUTH': 'some token',
        },
    }).node('.*', (overview) => {
        // I expect here to get an object having and id, title property
        push(null, overview.id);
    }).done((overview) => {
        push(null, _.nil);
    }).fail((reason) => {
        console.error(reason);
        push(null, _.nil);
    });
});
```

My problem is that I don't know what pattern to use node so that it matches each element of that array. As currently the items I am getting with the current setup are all the objects and the properties again:

```
425055
Foo
{ id: 227709, title: 'Foo' }
```

If the response would have had a property like:

```
{
  'overview': [],
}
```

I could have used `.overview.*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oboe has two ways of matching data, by path and by duck-typing.

#### By duck-typing

```
oboe('/data.json')
  .node('{id title}', function(x) {
    console.log('from duck-typing', x)
  })
```

#### By path

```
oboe('/data.json')
  .node('!.*', function(x) {
    console.log('from path matching', x)
  })
  //or also valid
  .node('!.[*]', function(x) {
    console.log('from path matching', x)
  })
```

In the path example, notice the `!` character. This refers to the root node of the tree, this pattern will only your three objects, not any of their own properties nested further down.

I made a [gomix](https://deafening-moose.gomix.me/) where you can view this working in the console, and also [view the source](https://gomix.com/#!/project/deafening-moose).

Answer (score 1):

Oboe.js supports duck typing:

```
.node('{id title}', (overview) => {
 }
```

Note that my json was flat, so this works. You result may vary for nested json.